# war packaging error grails 2.3.4

Tags: mysql, grails, war

I am using grails 2.3.4  and mysql is `mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'` and there are 163 gsp files, everytime when I run script as `war` or any other to create war file it shows following error

```
.Error 
|
WAR packaging error: encoded string too long: 70621 bytes
```

and there is no any gsp file more than 64kb and I have already commented `grails.project.fork`  in `buildconfig.groovy` but still I am getting problem please help.

Comment: Perhaps there's an artifact leftover from a previous build. Did you try grails clean all? Otherwise, can you tell which file it is breaking on through process of elimination by looking in the project's working directory and seeing which ones actually are compiling.

Comment: I have tried grails clean all but it is not working and there are only 101 gsp files in working directory but the overall gsp file is 163.How can I solve this? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is the answer you want to see :)  I can't imagine that  you have a good reason for being anywhere near the max size of a GSP. You shouldn't even know what the number is, only that it's way higher than you would ever need it to be.

You've either got a ton of code or a ton of HTML (or both) in these gigantic pages. There are plenty of obvious strategies for putting your GSPs on a diet. Use taglibs to move a lot of the code (which should not be used at all in a GSP, this isn't PHP) out of the view rendering tier and into the controller and service tiers where it belongs. You can extract static and mostly-static HTML blocks to includes/templates.

There's probably a lot of duplicated work here too - it's difficult to get this many files this large without a significant amount of copypasta. As a file gets very large it gets very hard to maintain an overall sense of what's where - our brains can only handle a certain amount of data before overloading. You also tend to start misplace small objects and partially eaten lunches in there, and that just makes things worse.

If you don't have the time for the significant refactoring this project likely needs if you've gotten this far off track, even a quick simple move to taglibs and templates without much thought about properly engineering the work would get things going. At least until you hit the limit again :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply,answer was helpful.